# Ampersand using Javascript & PHP

Tags: php, javascript, browser, scripting

I'm trying to redirect a page using javascript output using php.
The problem I'm having is passing the ampersand as you can see below.

Input

```
$url = 'number=1&id='.$usrid->id;

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.location = 'directory?$url';
    </script>";
```

Output

The above return on browser address bar this:

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/?number=1#038;id=190
```

Comment: What does the outputted <script> block look like in the HTML? Just break the Javascript for a second (e.g., delete a character) if you have problems with the page redirecting too fast.

Comment: exactly that. it just needed an exit after redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution to the above issue exactly as 'yar' suggests. The redirect was happening too fast and the php script didn't stop early. A simple exit function fixed the issue after redirect code.

Comment: Huh? If you were getting the #038; in your URL then you should have needed to do as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the URL first:

```
$url = htmlspecialchars('number=1&id=' . $usrid->id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `html_entity_decode` function

```
$url = 'number=1&id='.$usrid->id;

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.location = 'directory?".html_entity_decode($url)."';
</script>";
```